# What is the right way to install IO::Socket::SSL using Carton and custom LibreSSL/OpenSSL

Tags: perl, openssl, mojolicious, cpanm, libressl

Perl framework *Mojolicious* uses optional module **IO::Socket::SSL** for secured connections.

*Mojolicious* and **IO::Socket::SSL** must be installed using **Carton** (*cpanfile* contains dependencies list).
In order to use **IO::Socket::SSL** I need to have **Net::SSLeay** installed.
**Net::SSLeay** requires LibreSSL or OpenSSL installed.

On developer's server, a determined Perl project must use a determined LibreSSL/OpenSSL version:

```
$HOME/opt/LibreSSL/v1
$HOME/opt/LibreSSL/v...
$HOME/opt/OpenSSL/v1
$HOME/opt/OpenSSL/v...
```

My solution is to change **$PATH** system variable (for local custom LibreSSL/OpenSSL) before:

```
- execution "carton install" command
- running of a Perl project for testing
```

Is it right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining what instance of OpenSSL to link against is done by Net::SSLeay during its installation (IO::Socket::SSL is just an interface to that module). It explains in its [README](https://metacpan.org/source/CHRISN/Net-SSLeay-1.88/README):

```
    If your OpenSSL is installed in an unusual place, you can tell
    Net-SSLeay where to find it with the OPENSSL_PREFIX environment
    variable:
    OPENSSL_PREFIX=/home/mikem/playpen/openssl-1.0.2c perl Makefile.PL
```

Once installed, this no longer needs to be indicated to the respective Perl projects using that module.

Comment: Great! "cpanfile" allows do it so simple: on configure => sub { ... };

Comment: This is not a good idea, cpanfiles are not designed for arbitrary code. You should set it in the environment yourself (or as part of the larger build process).